# Check if each of two lists contains each of two elements in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was wondering if you can use list comprehensions somehow in order to check if two different lists contain all of two different elements.

I know it's maybe better to use an `and` and two different independent `all([list_comprehension])`, but that wouldn't escalate much if some day I needed to check, say, 5 things in 5 lists.

Answer (score 0):

...and after thinking about it for a while I found out how:

```
if all([all([x in l for x in [elem1, elem2]]) for l in [list1, list2]]):
```

The inner all() checks if all elements are in the list, and the outer all makes sure we do the same for each of the lists.

**MWE**

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 3, 5]

if all([all([x in l for x in [1, 3]]) for l in [list1, list2]]):
    print("found 1 and 3 in all of the lists")
```